# Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having problem in understanding this snippet of code.

```
import pandas as pd 


S1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index = ['a', 'b','c','d']) 


S2 = pd.Series([11, 22, 33, 44], index = ['a', 'bb','c','dd']) 


D1 = pd.DataFrame([S1,S2])
```

What I understand is there are two series and we are concatenating them to make a dataframe D. The result should be two columns and 6 rows.

With index of rows being : a b c d bb dd

The problem is that the answer in my book is given as 2 rows and 6 columns. How is it possible?

Comment: Well, you have 6 columns, as you deduced correctly. But some of the columns, namely `a` and `c`, will have two values, since S1 and S2 contained different values for the common columns.

Comment: I deduced that it should have 2 columns as a single series is used to create a dataframe with one column. Then two series should have two columns.

Comment: You can't have both `a  1` and `a 11`, so instead you get `a` as a column with two values, 1 and 11 etc,

Comment: Let's say the index of S2 is [aa,bb,cc,dd]. Then, would it have 8 rows with single column? It's quite confusing because we don't use index to 'index the columns' but here it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a dataFrame with a list of Pd.series objects like data, each element of the list is used to build a row of the resulting dataFrame.
So since you are providing [S1, S2] as the data, your dataFrame will have S1 as first row, and S2 as second row. As far as columns are concerned, the columns of the dataFrame is the Union of the columns of S1 and those of S2, it is why you have 6 columns in the resulting dataFrame.

I think this link will better help you to understand.

[pandas.Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html?highlight=dataframe#pandas.DataFrame)

Comment: List of series is used to create a column that was what I read. Check this link : https://www.tutorialgateway.org/python-series/#:~:text=A%20series%20in%20Python%20is,specified%20in%20the%20pandas%20module.&text=The%20default%20index%20value%20of,specify%20your%20own%20index%20values.

Comment: Since that we passed a list of numbers as data when building the dataFrame, each number will be used for a row. It's why we have 15 on the first row, 35 on the second row, and so on. But for your case the elements of the list are series. so the first series is used for the first row and the second serie for the seconde row.